# How to check and uncheck all checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with my code. I am trying to click on the button to check all of the checkboxes but nothing is working.

Here's my code.

```
<body>
<html>

<input type="checkbox" id="chk_boxes1" name="chk_boxes1" class="delete_customer"  value="<?php echo $rowTrackers['id']; ?>" />
<br>

<input type="checkbox" id="chk_boxes1" name="chk_boxes1" class="delete_customer"  value="<?php echo $rowTrackers['id']; ?>" />
<br>


<input type="checkbox" id="chk_boxes1" name="chk_boxes1" class="delete_customer"  value="<?php echo $rowTrackers['id']; ?>" />
<br>

<button type="button" name="btn_checkall" id="btn_checkall">Check all</button>

</html>
</body>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#btn_checkall').click(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
      $('.chk_boxes1').prop('checked', true);
    }else{
      $('.chk_boxes1').prop('checked', false);
    }
 });


});
</script>
```

I don't know where the trouble is coming from, but I guess that something have to do with the id, name or whatever it is that make it stop working.

Can you please show me the correct code that I could use to check and uncheck all of the checkboxes when I click on a button using with my code?

Comment: IDs need to be unique for one. You're using the wrong class for it also.

Comment: weird for a button to have a checked property

Comment: Looking at your console should have thrown you something.

Comment: @epascarello yeah I know. I have also tried it with `<input type="checkbox" class="btn_checkall" label="check all"  />check all
` still not working.

Comment: because you have no classname of chk_boxes1 on the elements. class selector does not match name

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner There is an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in line 21.

Comment: And that means you do not have jQuery.

Comment: @RobertJones you need initalize jQuery befor using it.

Comment: @RobertJones Start by fixing that, then check out the answers below. I'm no JS guru but I do remember a few things when it comes to id's/classes and the error you got which was mentioned in a comment that jQuery isn't loaded or not properly loading. If you have it somewhere in an included file, check the path for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to correct is that you have your html tag after your body tag. The html tag should for sure be the parent.

Other than this it looks like you have assigned "chk_boxes1" to id's instead of classes. If you change them to classes then things should work:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_boxes1" class="delete_customer chk_boxes1"  value="<?php echo $rowTrackers['id']; ?>" />
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_boxes1" class="delete_customer chk_boxes1"  value="<?php echo $rowTrackers['id']; ?>" />
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_boxes1" class="delete_customer chk_boxes1"  value="<?php echo $rowTrackers['id']; ?>" />
<br>
```

Also you are checking at button to determine checked status. This also will make the code not work. You can add and remove a class to the button if you want to change status or you can do something like this to check the group of checkboxes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#btn_checkall').click(function(){
    if ($('.chk_boxes1:checked').length == $('.chk_boxes1').length) {
      $('.chk_boxes1').prop('checked', false);
    }
    else {
      $('.chk_boxes1').prop('checked', true);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Ah thank you, I have forgot to include the jquery code and the class name. Problem are now solved. :)

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that you were checking the checkbox status using a button. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot going wrong there.

Firstly, your HTML tags are in the wrong order. Your document should start with `<html>` and end with `</html>`:

So, change your document to be like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        // your content
    </body>
</html>
```

And you also want to include your script at the bottom of your `<body>` or, as you're listening for DOM ready event, include the script in the `<head>`. So, adjust your `<script>` position to here:

```
<html>
    <body>
        // your content
        <script>
            // script here
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As for the main question, I suggest these changes:

HTML:

Remove the duplicate IDs. ID are meant to be totally unique for each element.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_boxes1" class="delete_customer"  value="<?php echo $rowTrackers['id']; ?>" />
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_boxes1" class="delete_customer"  value="<?php echo $rowTrackers['id']; ?>" />
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_boxes1" class="delete_customer"  value="<?php echo $rowTrackers['id']; ?>" />
<br>
```

jQuery:

Select the checkboxes by name instead of ID:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn_checkall').click(function(){
        var $chk_boxes = $('input[name="chk_boxes1"]');
        if($chk_boxes.prop('checked')) {
            $chk_boxes.prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $chk_boxes.prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As people have said, ids should be unique:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 //Use JQuery .on to attach event handler
 $('#btn_checkall').on('click', function(){
     //Get all checkboxes by class
     const $checkboxes = $('.delete_customer');
     //Use .each to iterate the checkboxes
     $checkboxes.each(function(){
         $(this).prop('checked', true);
     }); 
 });


});
```

Comment: Note; `const` needs a polyfill for IE11<

Comment: IE11 supports `const` not sure where you got that inclination?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I meant less than IE11 (<IE11). IE11 supports it.

Answer (score 0):

This is your html code.

```
<!-- Master checkbox to toggle all other checkboxes -->
<input type="checkbox" id="masterCheckbox"> Check All

<!-- Sample checkboxes with a common class -->
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> Checkbox 1
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> Checkbox 2
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> Checkbox 3
```

Here I use raw javascript-

```
// Get the master checkbox
var masterCheckbox = document.getElementById('masterCheckbox');

// Get all checkboxes with the class 'checkbox'
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');

// Function to toggle all checkboxes based on the master checkbox state
function toggleCheckboxes() {
    checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
        checkbox.checked = masterCheckbox.checked;
    });
}

// Attach event listener to the master checkbox
masterCheckbox.addEventListener('change', toggleCheckboxes);
```